# Contraction of tensor by metric in mean curvature flow

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors, submanifold, mean-curvature-flows

Picture below is from  the 255th page of
*Huisken, Gerhard*, [**Flow by mean curvature of convex surfaces into spheres**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214438998), J. Differ. Geom. 20, 237-266 (1984). [ZBL0556.53001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0556.53001).

In my view,
$$
A*\nabla A = g^{ia}h_{ij}\nabla _a h_{bc}   \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
g^{il}\nabla_j(Hh_{kl})= g^{il}h_{kl}\nabla _j H +  g^{il}H\nabla _j h_{kl}  \\
=g^{il}g^{ab}h_{kl}\nabla _j h_{ab} + g^{il}g^{ab}h_{ab}\nabla _{j}h_{kl}  \tag{2}
$$
I think the (2) has different from with (1). So, how to understand the step of  red line in picture ?

> > [image]

Comment: I think they are just abbreviating those three terms as $A *\nabla A$.

Comment: @ArcticChar  Do you mean the $A*\nabla A$ is the contraction of $A$ and $\nabla A$ ? But the times of contraction is not considered in this denotation. So,  $A*\nabla A$  can be linear combination of $g^{ia}h_{ij}\nabla _a h_{bc}$  and $g^{ia}g^{jb}h_{ij}\nabla _a h_{bc}$ ?

Comment: Yes, the no. of contractions does not matter.